# Can I use an NSPredicate in Swift with a nil argument?

Tags: core-data, swift, nspredicate

I'm trying to convert a project that uses Core Data from Objective-C to Swift.

The data model is structured so that I have one master folder which contains other folders - and those folders can also contain other folders, via a "parentFolder" relationship.

Currently, I do this in Objective-C to retrieve the master folder (it finds the only folder without a "parentFolder", and works as expected):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:"Folder"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentFolder == %@", nil];
```

In converting to Swift, I'd like to do the same thing:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Folder")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == %@", nil)
```

... but the compiler complains with "Missing argument label 'argumentArray:' in call. (I seem to be confusing it into thinking I need to use the NSPredicate(format: argumentArray:) method instead...)

Is there a correct way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It looks as if it is (with the current Xcode 6 beta 3 release) generally difficult
to pass `nil` in a variable argument list.

This *seems* to work:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == %@", 0)
print(predicate)
// Output: parentFolder == nil
```

But the **easiest solution** would be to simply write the predicate as

```
NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == nil")
```

Comment: Should it be "parentFolder == nil" or "parentFolder = nil"? I mean "==" vs. "="

Comment: @Roman: It makes no difference. You can use both `==`  and `=` in a predicate format string, compare https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215832

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution and fitting for you case would be to simply write the predicate as:

```
NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == nil")
```

But if it is necessary to insert nil as an argument you could use NSNull. This might be useful if you are using an Optional

```
let folderName: String? = nil
// ... assign folderName if available
NSPredicate(format: "parentFolder == %@", folderName ?? NSNull())
```

This will result in all folder with the same parent, if the parent is nil, it will fetch all folders without parent.